# How to set default __self__ property on javascript object

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I know to set a class object similar to below.

```
var myobj = {
    prop: 123,
    prop2: 234,
    prop3: 345
};
```

right now, if I want anything from myobj, I have to refer to the variable inside myobject; for example:  `myobj.prop` or `myobj.prop2`.

Can I set a default property, and refer to `myobj` as a whole, and return the default property?  similar to the `__self__` meta property in python?

Thanks...

Comment: But then how do you refer to the object itself? NB: in Python, `__self__` is defined for methods of an object, not the object itself.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, can you provide an example?

Comment: thanks....took me a minute to understand what you were saying.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "default property"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expressions, to get plain object references to return a predefined value instead of a reference, you can override object's [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method, like so:

```js
var myobj = {
    prop: 123,
    prop2: 234,
    prop3: 345
};
myobj.valueOf = function () {return 100;};

console.log(100 + myobj);
// The object name still works as a reference
console.log(myobj.prop);
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @arcee123 Note, that when logging `myobj`to the console, you will get the object description, console doesn't use object's `valueOf` method.

Comment: copy that.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, this *only* works when the object is used in a context where a primitive value is expected (e.g. arithmetic operation or string concatenation).